# C# Hide Text in Image

Tags: c#, image, steganography

I'm looking for a method of hiding some text in an image. Not like just putting text on the image in a hard to see color, but actually putting it into the code of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

Comment: @Entity - Start reading the different articles that are mentioned on the wikipedia article I have linked. There is no simple way to do it and you will need to figure one out by yourself.

Comment: A simple way of doing this is to store each bit of a data stream in the least significant bit of each of the RGB values of each pixel. However, there are better methods of Steganography, and as Oded said you should read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would say you're looking for steganopgraphy, but you indicate that you'd like to put it into the code of the file. Can you clarify what you mean by that? Are you doing this for the purposes of watermarking, or to markup the files for organizing them?